# Convert string to integer using map()

Tags: python

In the following i am trying to convert the first list to a integer list using the map function how can i achieve this

```
T1 = ['13', '17', '18', '21', '32']
print T1
T3=[map(int, x) for x in T1]
print T3
[[1, 3], [1, 7], [1, 8], [2, 1], [3, 2]]

Expected is:

T3=[13,17,18,21,32]
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
>>> T1 = ['13', '17', '18', '21', '32']
>>> T3 = list(map(int, T1))
>>> T3
[13, 17, 18, 21, 32]
```

This does the same thing as:

```
>>> T3 = [int(x) for x in T1]
>>> T3
[13, 17, 18, 21, 32]
```

so what you are doing is

```
>>> T3 = [[int(letter) for letter in x] for x in T1]
>>> T3
[[1, 3], [1, 7], [1, 8], [2, 1], [3, 2]]
```

Hope that clears up the confusion.

Comment: Your 2nd solution works fine but in the 1st one gives <map at 0x1cba94a5c50> error, for it to work you need to do this:

>>> T1 = ['13', '17', '18', '21', '32']
>>> T3 = map(int, T1)
>>> T3=list(T3)

or in short you can do this:
>>> T1 = ['13', '17', '18', '21', '32']
>>> T3 = list(map(int, T1))

Comment: @GhazaliShacklebolt Yes you are right because when I answered this it was in Python 2, i updated it like you said

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> T1 = ['13', '17', '18', '21', '32']
>>> print [int(x) for x in T1]
[13, 17, 18, 21, 32]
```

You don't need map inside your list comprehension. Map creates another list so you end up with a list of list.

Caveat: This will work if the strings are granted to be numbers otherwise it will raise exception.

Comment: If you want to use map(), for Python 3.6.0, you need to do: list(map(int,T1))

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this

```
>>>T1 = ['13', '17', '18', '21', '32']
>>>list(map(int,T1))
```

Comment: How is this any different from jamylak's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10145364/369450)?

Comment: I don't think this deserve a downvote, I just tried in Python3.6.0. Jamylak's answer gives result: `<map object at 0x05CEABF0>` but if you use list(map(int, T1)), it gives result [13, 17, 18, 21, 32]

Answer (score 2):

1.First,map function is map(func,iterable)
2.see this example:

```
T1=['13','17','18','21','32']
T3=[map(int, x) for x in T1]
print T3
[[1, 3], [1, 7], [1, 8], [2, 1], [3, 2]]
```

when choose x out,such as '13',is a sequence,so map(int,'13') return [1,3],so the iterable in map(func,iterable) is string.

3.see this example:

```
T1 = ['13', '17', '18', '21', '32']
>>>list(map(int,T1))
```

the iterable object in map function is list.so 'int' works on '13' as 13